# Tried to upvote a reddit submission but received a 404 HTTP response

Tags: python, http, response, reddit, praw

I'm new to coding and I suck. I hope to find help here.

I was playing around with the praw module for reddit and couldn't get the simple function upvote() to work.

Here's my code:

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(client_id='**************',
                     client_secret='**************',
                     user_agent='**************',
                     username='**************',
                     password='***********')

r.submission('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/9znyf2/today_is_my_18th_birthday_everyone/').upvote()
```

---

And here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\*****\*****\*****\*****\*****\A.py", line 11, in <module>
    r.submission('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/9znyf2/today_is_my_18th_birthday_everyone/').upvote()
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\mixins\votable.py", line 80, in upvote
    self._vote(direction=1)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\praw\models\reddit\mixins\votable.py", line 10, in _vote
    'id': self.fullname})
  File "C:\Users*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 465, in post
    params=params)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 506, in request
    params=params)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 130, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.NotFound: received 404 HTTP response
```

Comment: Someone donevoted! Could this person maybe link to a question that answers my question?

Answer (score 0):

PRAW is trying to use that URL as a post ID, not as a URL. `url` is the second argument to [`reddit.submission()`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit_instance.html#praw.Reddit.submission), so you'll need to use it as a named argument (`r.submission(url='https://www.reddit.com/...')`) to get the submission. After you do that everything should work as expected.